# How can i disable FINE level logs on JBoss EAP 7.2?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to disable FINE level logs on JBoss EAP7.2, is there way to disable them by modifying standalone.xml or another config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred option would be to use the web console or CLI. For a logger that is already configured:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=your.logger.name:write-attribute(name=level, value=INFO)
```

If the root logger has been set to fine/debug then you can change that like:

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name=level, value=INFO)
```

If you want to only see INFO and higher messages on a specific handler:

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=INFO)
```